# How does being pulled into a demesne mechanically work?

Tags: dresden-files

Demesnes, are described as the following:

> As a spirit that has been linked to the mortal world, you naturally create a space within the Nevernever tied to that place or concept. The space reflects the landscape of your "mind".

Ghosts possess a major advantage in their demense, in comparison to their mortal haunt. But the question is: how do they get there, or get someone they are targeting into there to make use of that?

As shown in the description, it is tied to the mortal location but I'm not certain how mechanically the tie functions.

Is it a specific power required such as swift transition - which seems to be an automatic success, if only one per scene? Although it also seems like it would only apply to the ghost itself moving and not bringing anyone else along.

Or is it a matter of a ghost having to simply roll a skill (discipline?) - and a PC having to roll (conviction?) to resist the transition and stay out of the Nevernever? Treat it like any other combat roll?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Demesne Power provides no way to force other characters into it

It allows some great control while within the Demesne, but no method to take a fight there... or even take yourself there. Such creatures should always have Swift Transition (and No Mortal Home if they're a ghost) and/or Worldwalker to facilitate this.

Swift Transition seems to be a self-only automatic success at transitioning into the Nevernever.

A being with Worldwalker could create a portal and use forced movement (via Grappling or similar magic) to send others to it's Demesne. More likely, they will retreat into their Demesne and give opponents no choice but to follow or face consequences.

---

There are no written occurrences of ghosts or similar dragging others to their Demesne in the Dresden Files. There are some instances of them invading others' minds and similar (which looks and probably works similar to a fight in a Demesne).

---

It would not be unreasonable for a creature to use Discipline or Conviction (or probably more appropriately a spell) to attempt to shift a target into the Nevernever. Said creature would also need to succeed against the Barrier as described in Your Story p283. I would allow targets to pick a Skill to use in defense, if they can justify its use, with the assumption that it would usually be Conviction or Discipline.

I would personally count this as a 1 point Power (similar to Mortal Stunts) if it is not done as a spell. They would, of course, also need a narrative reason to do so.